# SparkDataFrame.dtypes fails if a column has special chars..how to bypass and read the csv and inferschema

Tags: pyspark, spark-csv

Inferring Schema of a Spark Dataframe throws error if the csv file has column with special chars..

Test sample
foo.csv

id,comment
1, #Hi
2, Hello

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("footest").getOrCreate()
df= spark.read.load("foo.csv", format="csv", inferSchema="true", header="true")
print(df.dtypes)

raise ValueError("Could not parse datatype: %s" % json_value)
```

I found comment from Dat Tran on [inferSchema in spark csv package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628701/inferschema-in-spark-csv-package..but) how to resolve this...cann't we still inferschema before dataclean?

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test').enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").load("test19.csv")
print(df.dtypes)

Output:

[('id', 'int'), ('comment', 'string')]
```